# Synonyms for the word 'scold'

Tags: synonyms

What are the words we use in conversation as synonyms for "scold." Instead of saying "I scolded him" or "He scolded me," what are the alternative words we may use in our daily life?

Comment: To look up synonyms, use a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/scold) of your liking. This site is not a thesaurus, and not a free thesaurus lookup service.

Answer (score 2):

If "scold" is not sufficiently daily-life for you, we (as in 'Brits') have 'To tell off", variant "give him a right telling-off". You can also give someone "a piece of your mind" (someone's mind, apparently, is never a positive thing, how sad). Also very demotic, to the point of indecency, is to give someone a right "bollicking".

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answers have provided you with a wealth of options, but I will add one more to the pile that somehow got left out:

> [**admonish**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/admonish)

An example of its use in a [news article](http://www.inforum.com/news/crime/3728741-new-jersey-grandma-gets-55-years-killing-husband-keeping-remains-years):

> Before sentencing her in New Jersey Superior Court, Judge Michael Donio **admonished** Burroughs for her callousness, noting she left on a family vacation the day after the 2007 murder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different words / expressions. You can ***give someone a talking to***, ***reprimand him/her***, or ***give him/her a dressing down***. However, I am sure you will find plenty of alternatives if you take a look at any thesaurus.

For example, according to Collins (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/scold):

> ***scold***
>   verb
>   =  reprimand, censure, rebuke, rate, blame, lecture, carpet (informal), slate (informal, mainly British), nag, go on at, reproach, berate, tick off (informal), castigate, chide, tear into (informal), tell off (informal), find fault with, remonstrate with, bring (someone) to book, take (someone) to task, read the riot act, reprove, upbraid, bawl out (informal), give (someone) a talking-to (informal), haul (someone) over the coals (informal), chew out (US & Canadian, informal), give (someone) a dressing-down (informal), tear (someone) off a strip (British, informal), give a rocket (British & New Zealand, informal), vituperate, give (someone) a row, have (someone) on the carpet (informal) • "If he finds out, he'll scold me."
>       opposites: approve, praise, acclaim, applaud, compliment, commend, laud, extol